# TextView not getting displayed

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cardv2"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bordernew">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/url_image"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                 />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgchange1"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zonelett"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cardView">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Soil Type"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Sowing Date"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vswitch"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Area"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/soil_type0"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtArea"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vswitch"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vswitch"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14sd"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0001"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Irrigation Type"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0002"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Pump Switch"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView0003"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Valve Switch"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vswitch"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView0001"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14sd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15it"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView0001"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView0001"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView0001" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16ps"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView0002"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView0002"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView0002" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtvs"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView0003"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView0003"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView0003" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewreccom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="#9FD6F0C5"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/graph1c" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/graph1c"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtvs">

                <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
                    android:id="@+id/graph1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>




        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my xml file. I don't know why the TextView textViewreccom is not showing up. Can someone figure out why is it so?

This is my xml file. I don't know why the TextView textViewreccom is not showing up. Can someone figure out why is it so?

I AM SORRY. I HAD JUST BEEN CARELESS. I HAD DECLARED THE VIEW INVISBLE IN MY CODE. THIS QUESTION NEEDS TO BE DELETED OR CLOSED. I AM SORRY AND THANKS!

Comment: You haven't set the `text` to `textViewreccom` that's why you are seeing empty area.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I have addded some text in that programatically

Answer (score 2):

Your last `ConstraintLayout` with `@+id/graph1c` oberlaps that `Textview`

---

Possible Solution

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/graph1c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewreccom">
```

Comment: I tried this also, by setting the constraint layout according to the textview and the textview directly according to the parent but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: can you please add your related code ?

Comment: I am sorry I found out the problem. I had just set the view invisible in my code and had forgotten about it !

Comment: I am unable to delete or close the question now.

Comment: you can find it here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 1):

It is because the last Constraint Layout views(Overlap) over your Textview. Try updating the constraintLayout position. You have not set it below your txtvs. Set it as `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewreccom"`  eg:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/graph1c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewreccom">
```